# UNITY - The name `AssetDatabase' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine

I receive the following error when trying to build my game using unity:

> The name `AssetDatabase` does not exist in the current context

Can anyone please help.. I will appreciate all the help I can get..thank you

> Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
>
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 5 errors
>     at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:187 
>     at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems that in one of your scripts you use `AssetDatabase` which belongs to the `UnityEditor` namespace. It exists only inside the Unity Editor.

In a build the namespace `UnityEditor` does not exists -> You can't use anything of it in a built application!

---

So after beeing aware of that there are basically to solutions how to fix those errors when using e.g. custom editor scripts or some code blocks that shall only exist inside of the Unity Editor but not in a build:

1. Either make sure all scripts that are **only** editor scripts are placed in folders called `Editor`. Unity automatically excludes those in a build.
2. Or use the [#if pre-processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) with `UNITY_EDITOR`:

   ```c#
   #if UNITY_EDITOR
       using UnityEditor;
   #endif

   ...

   #if UNITY_EDITOR
       //some code here that uses something from the UnityEditor namespace
   #endif
   ```

Answer (score 6):

`AssetDatabase` only works in the editor. You can use `Resources.Load` instead.

For example:

`var jsonTextFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Text/jsonFile01");`

From [Unity's `Resources.Load` documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html):

> Loads the asset of the requested type stored at `path` in a [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html)
> folder.
>
> This method returns the asset at `path` if it can be found, otherwise it
> returns null. Note that the `path` is case insensitive and must not
> contain a file extension. All asset names and paths in Unity use
> forward slashes, so using backslashes in the path will not work.
>
> The `path` is relative to any folder named [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) inside the Assets
> folder of your project. More than one [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) folder can be used. If
> you have multiple Resources folders you cannot duplicate the use of an
> asset name. For example, a project may have [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) folders called
> `Assets / Resources/` and `Assets / Guns / Resources/`. The path does not
> need to include `Assets` and `Resources` in the string, for example
> loading a GameObject at `Assets / Guns / Resources / Shotgun.prefab`
> would only require `Shotgun` as the path. Also, if `Assets / Resources / Guns / Missiles / PlasmaGun.prefab` exists it can be loaded using `Guns / Missiles / PlasmaGun` as the `path` string. If you have multiple
> [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) folders you cannot duplicate the use of an asset name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below and it will work fine. Make sure your file is inside the "**Resources**" folder. Add the name without the extension of the file. This solution works for all cases.

```
Object[] GetSprites(string fileName)
{
    Object[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll(fileName);
    return sprites;
}
```